# No sound (dummy output or broken soft-hardware driver) on Debian 11

Tags: debian, audio, intel, realtek

I trying to configure fresh Debian 11, but stuck on sound driver at last 8 hours. My device (CHUWI Herobook Air) come from manufacturer with Windows 10 and sound dont work properly until install this Realtek/Intel SST audio driver from [this official manufacturer forum link](https://forum.chuwi.com/t/driver-audio-herobook-pro/24612/7).

I recently installed some packages (nonfree, realtek, intel-microcode), reinstalled pulseaudio, but nothing change.

My device data:

kernel version

```
uname -r 
5.10.0-14-amd64
```

resumed lspci

```
lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake Host Bridge (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 0

00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24, IOMMU group 0
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Device 2782:0303
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129, IOMMU group 2
    Memory at a1110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_sof_pci
```

filtered dmesg

```
dmesg | grep audio
[    9.319732] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    9.319987] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    9.320212] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    9.358982] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: use msi interrupt mode
[    9.382512] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: hda codecs found, mask 4
[    9.382517] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[    9.382524] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 0
[    9.386190] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/sof/sof-glk.ri
[    9.386231] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: warning: unknown sof_ext_man header type 6 size 0x20
[    9.386233] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: Firmware info: version 1:7:0-47d07
[    9.386235] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: Firmware: ABI 3:18:1 Kernel ABI 3:17:0
[    9.386236] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: warn: FW ABI is more recent than kernel
[    9.386243] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: warning: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[    9.386245] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: warning: unknown sof_ext_man header type 5 size 0x20
[    9.503708] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: Firmware info: version 1:7:0-47d07
[    9.503711] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: Firmware: ABI 3:18:1 Kernel ABI 3:17:0
[    9.503713] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: warn: FW ABI is more recent than kernel
[    9.514738] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/sof-tplg/sof-hda-generic-idisp.tplg
[    9.514759] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: Topology: ABI 3:18:1 Kernel ABI 3:17:0
[    9.514761] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: warn: topology ABI is more recent than kernel
[    9.518468] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:0e.0: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
```

In Windows 10 the sound driver information is:

```
Device PCI \VEN_8086&DEV_3198&SUBSYS_03032782&REV_06
```

Output just refer to "Dummy output"...
Happy if some helps.

Comment: At least your system does not appear happy with the firmware you installed. Have you tried without any firmware, just making sure that CONFIG_SND CONFIG_SND_SOC CONFIG_SND_SOC_SOF_PCI are selected in the kernel .config as it seems to be suggested there : https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:8086-3198-1043-1e70 ?

Comment: Apart from this, you could probably consider https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=268248 and from the last post conclude that in accordance with what your dmesg warns, the firmware you installed is just not compatible with your kernel version.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I updated Kernel to 5.16 backport, kernel version warns disappears, but still dummy output. DMESG outputs still "sof_ext_man header type 3 size". If include "snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1", aplay lists only HDMI outputs. I haven't tried the kernel settings yet, but I will as soon as I have time.

Comment: Tried other distros, like Fedora or Manjaro... no sucess.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in an XPS 9710 laptop running on Debian 11.3. After adding some lines in the grub as suggested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225463/18-04-no-sound-intel-sound-card-snd-hda-intel-not-working) and related posts, which in my case did not work, I updated the firmware version (firmware-sof-signed 1.7-1) to the version 2.0-1 for Debian 12 -bookworm- using the Synaptic Package Manager because somewhere I read that otherwise, I could get incompatibility issues that could brake the OS. 

Eventually, using the new firmware version (I added the bookworm channel to the /etc/apt/sources.list first), Synaptic installed a bunch of other packages and I ended up having Debian 12 as OS, which actually recognized the audio!
However, I had to roll back to Debian 11 (Yes, a brand new installation of Debian 11) because I had other hardware issues with the screen (dimming unexpectedly) and other software such as Docker in Debian bookworm. 

So in conclusion:

- If you only want to have the sound working, you can upgrade to Debian 12 (with pitfalls, maybe)
- Another option should be upgrading the firmware-sof-signed to a later version like 2.0-1 only. I am new in Linux so, I still don't know how to do it. Any help will be appreciated, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the DSP capabilities, and if the Debian 11 kernel/firmware has trouble with the [Sound Open Firmware](https://thesofproject.github.io/latest/architectures/host/linux_driver/architecture/sof_driver_arch.html#support-for-high-definition-audio-hd-audio) needed to drive the DSP, you could also try to disable the SOF part and just use the "legacy" snd_hda_intel driver. (Read up on blacklisting kernel modules to find out how to do that).

As you mentioned you had to install some Realtek driver, you still may or may not have problems with the Codec itself (if it is a Realtek one), but the question doesn't contain enough information about that.

Have a look at `/proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` or `dmesg` to see which codecs, if any, are identified.

(Brief background: The Intel HDA architecture connects to the main system, and then drives and additional chip, also called codec, through a bus from the Sound Controller. The codec may follow the standard, or require addititional driver quirks etc.).

When testing, make sure to take Pulseaudio out of the equation, just to eliminate an additional layer of complexity. So deinstall Pulseaudio or stop/suspend it. Use `aplay`, `alsamuxer` etc. to directly access the ALSA layer, which connects to the kernel modules.